# Making multiple forms look like one form in Windows Forms App c#

Tags: c#, forms

I'm working on a windows forms app and I need to have a few different screens. One screen with a list of options, then when they select one it will load a different screen. I want this to look nice, not the old way of having a second form a bit over from the first, and now you have two forms on the screen. I want a smooth transition from one display to the next, like when a browser changes. Is there a way to just have it all in 1 form, with the controls changing, or at least have this appearance? (ie pop up immediately on top of other form with exact same size and close older form)

I feel like this is really obvious but I can't find it anywhere. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Make all your 'sub-forms' into separate user controls and your single form can just load those user controls as needed.

Answer (score 0):

1st Approach:
Use Panels, you can put all your controls (which you want to hide or show upon clicking on selected options) inside the panel. Then just hide or show this panel according to the options selected.

2nd Approach:
You can use each windows form for each option. Just make all windows form size equal and put these lines into each windows form "form_load" function.
This code will open your windows form exactly in center of the screen.

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Screen src = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen;
 int src_height = src.Bounds.Height;
 int src_width = src.Bounds.Width;

 //put the form in the center

 this.Left = (src_width - this.Width) / 2;
 this.Top = (src_height - this.Height) / 2;
```

To close previous form use

```
this.close();
```

To open another window use this line

```
Form_Name frm = new Form_Name();
frm.Show();
```

**NOTE:** using **this.close();** in main form will close all windows forms currently showing including main form This is because it is the parent window from which other windows are opened. If we close parent window, application will have to close all its child windows.

To prevent this problem use **this.Hide();** to hide the main form not closing it.
If controls on windows form are in larger number, use 2nd Approach. Otherwise I recommend you to use 1st Approach.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C) to very simple MDI application. It will give you an idea how it works.

Basic concept:

- You have one main form `MainForm` what will be parent to other forms. Set [IsMdiContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) = true
- Create child forms and set [MdiParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent(v=vs.110).aspx) to `MainForm` instance.

Sample:

```
// Create a new form to represent the child form.
Form child = new Form();
// Make the new form a child form.
child.MdiParent = this;
// Display the child form.
child.Show();
```